# Attempting to send data from a UIPicker to Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uipickerview

So I have figured out how to send textfield data in to the database whilst giving each customer's order a unique key, in the next view or next screen, I need to limit what selections a customer makes so I have placed instead of a text field a UIPicker with various options. I need the option that the customer selects to also appear in my database under the same key as the one used in the previous screen.

```
class flavorViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    var customerInfo: FIRDatabaseReference!
    @IBOutlet weak var flavorPicker: UIPickerView!

    var flavors: [String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        FIRApp.configure()
        customerInfo = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Customer Info");

        self.flavorPicker.dataSource = self
        self.flavorPicker.delegate = self

        //List Picker Data Here
        flavors = ["Double Apple", "Watermelon Mint", "Blueberry Mint", "Grape Mint", "Geisha", "Sex on the Beach"]
    }

    // The number of columns of data
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // The number of rows of data
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return flavors.count
    }

    // The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return flavors[row]
    }

    func flavorselected() {
        let key = customerInfo.childByAutoId().key

        let flavor = ["id": key,"flavor selected": flavorPicker.selectedRow as Int ]
    }

    @IBAction func checkoutButton(_ sender: Any) {
        flavorselected()
    }
```

Here is all the code I have for setting everything up however, I get an error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> Int' to type 'Int' in coercion

Furthermore, while I haven't attempted this yet, will this selection be merged with the data the user has entered in the previous screen to the database? Or will it create a separate entry.

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: let flavor = ["id": key,"flavor selected": flavorPicker.selectedRow as Int ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is on this line:

```
let flavor = ["id": key,"flavor selected": flavorPicker.selectedRow as Int ]
```

and it is caused by:

```
flavorPicker.selectedRow as Int
```

`selectedRow` is a function that takes and `Int` parameter. You need to change this to:

```
let flavor: [String: Any] = ["id": key,"flavor selected": flavorPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, debugger is giving me another error and is asking me to add "as [String: Any]" to the end of this statement would that have any impact positive or negative?

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect that your array contains different kinds of values.